# IBActions foo and foo:

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ibaction

In Interface Builder I in Library->Classes when I select a class that I made in XCode, then display the Actions, I can see two with the same name:

```
foo
foo:
```

What is the difference between these two foos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` is a method that doesn't accept any arguments. `foo:` passes an argument or arguments into its method.

**Example:**

```
-(IBAction)foo;
```

will be shown as `foo` in IB.

```
-(IBAction)foo:(id)sender;
```

will be shown as `foo:` in IB.

I don't know why they have the same name, do you have them set that way?

Comment: I made one in IB and then I went in XCode and made another one so that I could write the implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

IB assumes if your creating the class files using IB that you will using the *sender* and so it creates the construct

```
-(IBAction)foo:(id)sender;
```

You usually will need info about the *sender* so I would stick with that construct. If you don't need the *sender* in your implementation, simply ignore it.

```
-(IBAction)foo:(id)sender {
    [someObject doAMethod];
}
```